# uploading file doesn't work in linux

Tags: php, linux

So I have code for uploading image to server that actually work when I tested it on the windows system, but as soon as I put it on Linux, it is doesn't work. So problem is that it doesn't give me any mistake, in the end it put the link on data base, but doesn't put the image in the folder where it spouse to be. So the problem is only in uploading image in server. 
So here is the code where the path and image download.

```
$path = "../users/".$IDN."/";
        if(preg_match('/[.](JPG)|(jpg)|(jpeg)|(JPEG)|(gif)|(GIF)|(png)|(PNG)$/',$_FILES['imgupload']['name']))
        {
            $filename = $_FILES['imgupload']['name'];

                $source = $_FILES['imgupload']['tmp_name'];
                $target = $path.$filename;
                move_uploaded_file($source, $target);
// and other funny actions
```

Comment: Does the path "../users" exist in the linux system?

Comment: yes, it is, I just wondering do I have a mistake in code that supouse to upload the file, because in windows it works fine

Comment: Can You Tell Us What Is `$IDN`?

Comment: session_start();
   $IDN=$_SESSION['IDN']; I have folder users where I have other folders with names of $IDN,

Answer (score 0):

What is the owner/group of that ../users/$IDN? Could you print out the output of following command:

ls -l ../users

Also what is your web service? Is it apache? What username your web server is running with?

If your web service user does not have permission to write in target directory, then you can't really write unless you change permission.

Also try to change error_reporting to ALL in your php.ini to see the error message.

Comment: drwxr-xr-x 2 user user 4096 Jun 17 11:20 14   web server is apache. Can you help me to change the permission for web server, my user have a permissions, but the how add permissions to apache?

Comment: You have to run this on ../users/ directory, the top directory: chown -R apache:apache ../users; and you have to be root or the owner of that directory (user).